# Cython letting go of gil when I need size of numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, cython, python-3.3, gil

When I try to compile the below code, I get the error

> ```
> return sign_match.sum() / y_true.shape[0]
>                                      ^
> ```
>
> Converting to Python object not allowed without gil

Is there an easy way to overcome this? The most viable solution I can think of is to pass in the length of the arrays as another argument. I am using python 3.3.5.

```
cimport cython
cimport numpy as np


# Returns negative mean-squared error
cdef double negative_mse(np.ndarray[double, ndim=1] y_true,
                         np.ndarray[double, ndim=1] y_pred) nogil:
    cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=1] err
    err = y_true - y_pred

    return -(err * err).sum()  / y_true.shape[0]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`y_true` and `y_pred` are arrays, and thus Python objects.  Therefore any operation using them will require the `gil`, not just taking the shape.

Try compiling without the the `nogil`, and look at the `-a` html.  Which lines are dark yellow, with many Python object references?

```
+11:     return -(err * err).sum()  / y_true.shape[0]
  __pyx_t_7 = PyNumber_Multiply(((PyObject *)__pyx_v_err), ((PyObject *)__pyx_v_err)); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_7)) __PYX_ERR(0, 11, __pyx_L1_error)
  __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_7);
  __pyx_t_8 = __Pyx_PyObject_GetAttrStr(__pyx_t_7, __pyx_n_s_sum); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_8)) __PYX_ERR(0, 11, __pyx_L1_error)
  __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_8);
  __Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_7); __pyx_t_7 = 0;
  ....
```

Just a portion of the expanded C code for your file.  See all the `Pyx..` calls.  They all require the `gil`.

http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html shows that you can use `nogil` on a memoryview of an numpy array.

Drawing from the memoryview guide I wrote this alternative function

```
cpdef double neg_mse_view(double[:] y_true, double[:] y_pred):
    cdef double x, res
    cdef int I
    I = y_true.shape[0]
    res = 0
    for i in range(I):
        x = y_true[i]-y_pred[i]
        res += -(x*x)
    res = res/I
    return res
```

This can be called in the same way.  These timings show a 2x speedup.  `nogil` works, but doesn't make a difference.

```
In [10]: a=np.arange(1000000.)
In [11]: timeit negmse.negative_mse(a,a-10)
10 loops, best of 3: 16.9 ms per loop
In [12]: timeit negmse.neg_mse_view(a,a-10)
100 loops, best of 3: 7.17 ms per loop
In [13]: timeit negmse.neg_mse_nogil(a,a-10)
100 loops, best of 3: 7.19 ms per loop
```

For a function this simple, the pure numpy version is basically as good:

```
In [20]: timeit ((a-(a-10))**2).sum()/a.shape[0]
100 loops, best of 3: 16.8 ms per loop
```

Comment: ty ty! haha I would think numpy would be just as fast. I wanted to use the nogil function (a small part of a bigger process) inside a loop. I just wanted a simple example to get started with. This is extremely helpful.